# datatype hexadecimal

Tags: objective-c

Can Anybody help me in converting the string to hex value in OBJECTIVE C

i have to pass the hex value to a macro... 
i have it in string like ---- 0xfffff
how can i convert this string to hex and in what data type....

Answer (score 4):

Use `-[NSScanner scanHexLongLong:]`:

```
NSString * s = @"0xFFFFF";
unsigned long long ull = 0;
NSScanner * scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:s];
[scanner scanHexLongLong:&ull];
NSLog(@"%llu", ull); //logs 1048575
```